# Error in phpMyAdmin 4.1.11 - Advisor.class.php

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get an error if I try to run the phpmyadmin advisor (status -> advisor) with pma 4.1.11.

In log:

> `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /opt/phpMyAdmin4.1.11/libraries/Advisor.class.php(343) : eval()'d code on line 1,...`

After some research I found the following two expressions causing this problem:

(1):

> `implode(' ',ADVISOR_formatByteDown(1073741824, 2, 2)),
>   implode(' ',ADVISOR_formatByteDown(1073741824, 2, 2))`

(2):

```
0, 2,
```

so, yes, i do understand, why (line 343)

```
eval('$value = ' . $expr . ';');
```

doesn't work, but is there some solution for it, since the advisor always comes back with http 500 and this is probably caused by this (there are no other errors in log).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it [was a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4347/), but it's been fixed. I suggest upgrading your phpMyAdmin installation.